# Import Error module "pmw" from tkinter using Python 3 Debian

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I try to import the module to work with Pmw tkinter Python 3 am using Raspberry-Pi, I get the following error.

```
from tkinter import *

import Pmw


importError: no module named "pmw"
```

Comment: have you installed the pmw module? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for the reply, if I have installed the Pmw module with the following command,"sudo apt-get install python-pmw" in python 2 operates normally, the problem comes when you try to work in Python 3, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To import `Pmw` in python3 in Debian/Ubuntu systems, do the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install pmw
```

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is tkinter (no capital T) in python 3 so just change the 'T' to 't', or vice versa for earlier version.